# PHP , HTML , how to show a form on click on link?

Tags: php, html

I'm beginner to PHP and HTML
now I'm trying to build Login and Register System ...
Assuming that on my home page I have two forms and I want them to appear just if the user clicked on a word "LOGIN" , or "REGISTER"

so I wrote a php code like that:

```
<?php
switch ($x)
{
    case 'register' :

?>
        <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        </form>

<?php
    break;

    case 'login':
?>
        <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        </form>
<?php
    break;
}
?>
```

Now I wrote a html code like that :

```
<h1>Click here to <a href =""> Login</a> or <a href =""> Register</a></h1>
```

So ,  at `<a href ="">` how can I make `x` equals to `'login'` or `'register'` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to check these codes below!

**PHP script:**

```
<?php
switch ($_GET['x']) {
    case 'register':
    echo '<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    </form>';
    break;
    case 'login':
    echo '<form action="register.php" method="POST">
    </form>';
    break;
}
?>
```

**HTML code:**

```
<h1>Click here to <a href="page.php?x=login">Login</a> or <a href="page.php?x=register">Register</a></h1>
```

Comment: That what I wanted :) Thx :)

Comment: @Merna Actually, there's a mistake on the previous codes, that's why I've revised it.

Answer (score 2):

Well php can do this, to me, jQuery will be the best. You can achieve it with following code:

```
jQuery:


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#panel1").hide();
    $("#panel2").hide();
    $(".btn-slide1").click(function(){
        $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow");
    });

    $(".btn-slide2").click(function(){
        $("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="slide"><a href="#" class="btn-slide1">Register</a></p>
<div id="panel1">
    Register Content will goes here!
</div>

<p class="slide"><a href="#" class="btn-slide2">Login</a></p>
<div id="panel2">
    Login Content will goes here!
</div>
```

Do not forget to check the official page of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to know more about its magic!!

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript or jquery form this

```
<a href ="" id="login"> Login</a>

<a href ="" id="register"> Register</a>
```

//Using jquery

```
$("#login").click(function(){
//Show your login form here
});

$("#register").click(function(){
//Show your register form here
});
```